# Element.getattribute("Value") and gettext() is not working for selenium webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying get value or text from element, but it is not working. Kindly help me in this. Below is the path and Web Element.

Link:https://www.tcsion.com/OnlineAssessment/ScientificCalculator/Calculator.html

Element:

```
<input id="keyPad_UserInput" class="keyPad_TextBox" maxlength="30" readonly="" type="text">
```

Comment: Go through [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this forum. Paste your code that you have tried. what is the output (or error) that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to get value from textfield.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("keyPad_UserInput")).click();              
String text=driver.findElement(By.id("keyPad_UserInput")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;
driver.findElement(By.id("keyPad_UserInput")).getAttribute("value")

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript executor to get value value from input field.

```
String return_value = (String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('keyPad_UserInput').value");
```

hope this help !

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code,you will get the text entered in the field.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='keyPad_btn2']")).click();
WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='keyPad_btn2']"));
    String value = firstName.getText();
    System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Input Type Is Readbleonly  you will get Data By using `getAttribute("value")` method Only

```
    driver.get("https://www.tcsion.com/OnlineAssessment/ScientificCalculator/Calculator.html");
                System.out.println("  Page");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='keyPad_UserInput']"));
                System.out.println("value using getAttribute ::"+ele.getAttribute("value"));
                System.out.println("value using getText::"+ ele.getText()); //its return empty or null
```

***OutPut*** :

```
 value using getAttribute :: 0
 value using getText      ::
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this it is not working.

Comment: you got any exception ? i tired above code its working fine

Comment: Thanks for the update , I will try this one more time and I will let u know

Comment: Working successfully!!